# Convergence in $L^{\infty}$ norm implies convergence in $L^1$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a measure space and $f$ measurable. Assume the measure space $X$ has finite measure. If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^{\infty}$-norm , then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^{1}$-norm.

This is my approach:

We know $||f_n-f||_{\infty} \to 0 $ and by definition $||f_n-f||_{\infty} =\inf\{M\geq 0: |f_n-f|\leq M \}.$ Then
\begin{align}
||f_n-f||_1\
&=\int |f_n-f| dm\
&\leq \int|f_n|dm+\int|f|dm\
\end{align}

I don't know how to proceed after that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be also interested in the [embeddings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings) of the $L^p$ spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any function $g$, $||g||_1 = \int_X|g(m)|dm \leq \int_X||g||_\infty dm = \mu(X)*||g||_\infty$   (as $|g(m)| \leq ||g||_\infty$ almost everywhere); $||g||_\infty \geq \frac{||g||_1}{\mu(X)}$, so if $||f_n-f||_\infty$ tends to zero, then $||f_n-f||_1$ tends to zero as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is using the triangle inequality when you don't have to. Here,
$$
\|f_n-f\|_1=\int|f_n-f|dm\leq\|f_n-f\|_\infty\,\int1dm=\|f_n-f\|_\infty\,m(X)\to0.
$$

Comment: The same also holds for $L^p, p \in (0,\infty)$ instead of $L^1$, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. $\ $