# Relation of convergence in $L^\infty$ and $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$. Now, let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions such that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^\infty(\mu)$. Does this imply that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^p(\mu)$ for any $p < \infty$?

If so, what is a formal argument, or even better, a reference for this statement?

Comment: [Here is the case $p=1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124546/convergence-in-l-infty-norm-implies-convergence-in-l1-norm?rq=1), and the proof can be adapted to the general case with very small corrections. There is also a link, in the comments, to general the fact that, if $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, for all $1\le p<q\le\infty$, $L^q$ is continuously embedded in $L^p$.

Comment: If $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty}\leq \epsilon$ with $\epsilon<1, p>1$, then $\|f_n\|_{L^p}\leq \epsilon^p\mu(\Omega)$. This converges to zero as $\epsilon$ tends to zero. I am not sure iif the statement holds for $0<p<1$

Comment: @GregordeCillia: There is a minor mistake: it is $\| f_n\|_p \le \epsilon \mu(\Omega)^\frac1p$. (This is true even for $0<p\le 1$).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, thanks for the correction.